# Return an url list from a nested object with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm messing up with Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to replicate the "gem store" example from angular JS to make it work with DRF.

I have this model

```
# Create your models here.
class Gem(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{name} | {price}".format(name=self.name,price=self.price)



class GemGallery(models.Model):
    gem=models.ForeignKey(Gem,related_name="gallery")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler)
```

Don't worry about the upload_path_handler, it just persist my entity and then I get the generated ID to name the file and save it locally.

The problem is with my serializer, I'm trying to use a "SlugRelatedField" which points to the image attribute, since it should be returning an url but I get this exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError at /listGems/ 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4
>   in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)

probably the url has a character that the serializer doesn't support or I don't know.

So I just want to get a list of Gems and inside of every gem get a list of urls from the GemGallery set that comes with the object.

This is my serializer:

```
class GemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gallery = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field="image")
    class Meta:
        model = models.Gem
        fields = ('id', 'name','description','price','gallery')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a SerializerMethodfield

```
class GemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gallery = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_gallery(self,instance):
        images=[]
        for gallery in instance.gallery.all():
            images.append(gallery.image.url)
        return images

    class Meta:
        model = models.Gem
        fields = ('id', 'name','description','price','gallery')
```